# Use helper function in custom form_validation.php - CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have custom validation form in CI3 - form_validation.php. Something like this:

```
$config = [
 'validation_key'=>[
   [

       'field' => 'name',
       'label' => 'Name',
       'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]|alpha_numeric'
   ],
   [
       'field' => 'country',
       'label' => 'name',
       'rules' => 'in_list[....]'
   ],
]
```

And I have helper with function that returns array of all contries. What I want is to add this helper function in country field validations to check is it valid country name. How can I do that ? There is nothing for adding helpers in form_validation.php in CI3 documentation.

Comment: Callable - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

Answer (score 0):

It posible only if you add you custom colback rule and provide your finction inside. Like this:

```
$config = [
 'validation_key'=>[
   [

       'field' => 'name',
       'label' => 'Name',
       'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]|alpha_numeric|callback_custom_plugin'
   ],
   [
       'field' => 'country',
       'label' => 'name',
       'rules' => 'in_list[....]'
   ],
]

...

function custom_plugin($value){
    return your_helper_function($value);
}
```